# Getting results from two tables by using SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2  MySQL tables:

[image]

I store the `admin_vat_id` in the `Fac__Article` table which is actually a reference to the `id` of the `Fac__Admin_vat`:

[image]

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to get all `Fac__Article`  table's entries, but at the `admin_vat_id` column, where it normally would display the integer value, I want to display the float value of the column `rate` of the table `Fac__Admin_vat`.

I guess I have to use the select and union keyword, but I don't know how to implement this select query. Please guide me with knowledge in solving this problem.

Comment: can you show some sample output you require?

Comment: its a simple join query nothing more than that

Comment: I think you should use the `LEFT JOIN` instead of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    fa.id,
    fav.rate,
    fa.article_number,
    fa.name,
    fa.description,
    fa.unit,
    fa.price,
    fa.stock,
    fa.stock_warning,
    fa.visible
FROM `fac_article` fa
LEFT JOIN `fac_admin_vat` fav
    ON fa.admin_vat_id = fav.id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d55fb/1/0)

Comment: +1 for the example. But why are you using fa.columnname, and fav.column name? Will it work without it?

Comment: nope. that is an alias for the name of the table. fa is your Fac__Admin table, while fav is the Fac__admin_vat.

Comment: The `fa` and `fav` following the table names are assigning alias' to them for use elsewhere. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (correct the table names if i misspelled): `SELECT *, Fac__Admin_vat.rate FROM Fac__Article LEFT JOIN Fac__Admin_vat ON Fac__Admin_vat.id = Fac__Article.admin_vat_id`

Comment: Please do not edit my answer with your comment. Why isn't that good for you? You sad, you want everything from the `Fac__Article` table, and the `rate` related on Fac__Article.id to Fac__Article.admin_vat_id

Comment: Although your answer didn't solve my problem it pointed me to the right direction. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join, a rough example below.

```
SELECT *, Fac__Admin_vat.rate as admin_rate FROM Fac__Article LEFT JOIN Fac__Admin_vat ON Fac__Article.admin_vat_id = Fac__Admin_vat.id
```

This will allow you to use admin_rate in your code to get the data you want. Hope this helps.